# Storyboard animation only displays last frame

Tags: animation, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1

I have to create an animation for a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I want to change the `ImageSource` property of my `Page.Background` to display an animated splash when the app launches.

I used this sample as a model: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823622/Images-Animation-By-Using-Story-Board-in-Windows-P

In my code, the animation lasts 8 seconds for 80 images, but the screen stays black for 8 seconds, then only displays the last frame.

```
private void setupStoryboard()
{
    storyboard = new Storyboard();

    var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, BackgroundBrush);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "ImageSource");            

    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 80; i++)
    {                
        var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
        {                    
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100 * i)), //Time Interval
            Value = String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Animation/splash{0:D2}.png", i) //Source of images
        };

        animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
    }

    Resources.Add("Storyboard", storyboard); //Add story board to resources
}
```

This code is called from `OnNavigatedTo`, and I have a button to call `storyboard.Begin();`

This problem appears on simulator and device.

**Update:** The problem persists with a greater interval (1000ms), and smaller images (30KB jpg instead of 240KB png)

**Update:** Same problem with an `<Image>` tag

**Update:** Still not solved, but I managed to obtain the desired effect. I created a DispatcherTimer to manually change the image. Unfortunately, this creates a nasty flickering effect. I had to add a second identical image on top of the first, and alternate between the two: imageA loads source1, imageB loads source2, imageA loads source3, ImageB loads source4...

Mission completed, with duct tape.

Comment: How big these images are?

Comment: 1920x1080, from 21 to 240KB. The problems happens even if I load/display one image out of 10

Comment: So I gusess 100 ms may be not enough to load them. Maybe try to convert them to JPEG format because it loads much faster than PNG.

Comment: to test if the 100ms is to fast try making the animation slower or try smaller images just for test.

Comment: Same problem with JPG of ~30KB, and 1000ms between each frame

Comment: Kinda solved, with a weird solution not involving a storyboard.